# Not able to style p-progressbar (indeterminate) using primeng in angular

Tags: angular, progress-bar, primeng

Not able to style p-progressbar (indeterminate) using primeng in angular

app.component.html (plain html)

```
<p-progressBar mode="indeterminate" class="someClass"></p-progressBar>
```

app.component.css (tried with two styles as shown below)

```
.ui-progressbar.ui-progressbar-indeterminate {
background: #8ec5fc;
height: 4px;
}
.someClass {
  background: #8ec5fc;
  height: 4px;
 }
```

app.module.ts

```
import {ProgressBarModule} from 'primeng/progressbar';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  FormsModule,
  ProgressBarModule
  ],
 declarations: [
 AppComponent
 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

none of the styles are being applied.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, its very simple and here is that,

```
<p-progressBar mode="indeterminate" **[style]="{height: '4px', 
 background:'red'}**"></p-progressBar>
```

This is it ..!